Why is this cubic a sum of three lines? (notation from Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry by Miles Reid)
In section $2.9$ of Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry by Miles Reid we define $3$ lines $L_1$, $M_2$ and $L_3$.

Consider the cubic $D_1 = L_1+M_2+L_3$.

I'm sure it's defined somewhere in the book, but I can't find it. What does this notation mean?

Might it just be the set-theoretic union of these lines? I've seen this notation for union in old papers (can't say anything about algebraic geometry, though).

This is standard notation for divisors, but it doesn't look like Reid has introduced the notion at this point in the book. Then again I don't think UAG is meant to be a particularly careful and rigorous treatment.

He means the cubic curve given by the union of the three lines. If you prefer, multiply the three (homogeneous?) linear polynomials to get the defining equation of the cubic curve.

Thanks all for your help, if someone wants to give this an an answer I'll accept it.
